2nd useEffect being called before 1st useEffect completes its execution
I have a component which calls this createAsyncThunk method and sets the state.config as follows-
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
        try {
            dispatch(setMode(FINANCIALS));
            let config= await FinancialsServices.getConfig();
            await FinancialsUtility.setPermissions(entityId,config);
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    })()
}, []);

//useEffect responsible for fetching data as per grid mode
useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async (addParams) => {
        if ((financialState.config && Object.keys(financialState.config).length)) {
            await FinancialsServices.getData(getPayload(addParams));
        }
    }

   getData({})
}, [currentIndex, financialState.currentSheet.name,
    financialState.currentTag,
    financialState.currentPeriodType.value,
    financialState.currentCurrency, financialState.financialsGridMode])

this getData() and getConfig() functions are actually createAsyncThunk functions and In fetchFinancialConfig.fullfilled I set all default values of
financialState.currentSheet.name,
        financialState.currentTag,
        financialState.currentPeriodType.value,
        financialState.currentCurrency, financialState.financialsGridMode

elements present in array of dependency of 2nd useEffect
static async getConfig() {
        try {
            const configResponse = await store.dispatch(fetchFinancialConfig());
            return configResponse.payload
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    static async getData(payload) { // makes a dispatch request to fetch data for particular ratio
        try {
            const dataResponse: any = await store.dispatch(fetchFinancialData({ payload }));
            return dataResponse;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

and I want this await FinancialsUtility.setPermissions(entityId,config);
to execute before getdata useEffect and after fetching config through getConfig useEffect
How can I achieve it? I assume since I am changing array of dependencies attributes in extraReducers fullfilled therefore the 2nd useEffect is being triggered. But I want FinancialsUtility.setPermissions(entityId,config); to execute before the 2nd useEffect.
